# Wordpress + Gravity Form + Custom Post Types + Flickr integration

Tags: forms, wordpress, flickr, custom-post-type, gravity

I need to find a solution this scenario.
I am trying to achieve the ability to let user post a picture using file upload or paste a Flickr (or Picasa) link of a photo (not a set or gallery or favorites of an user). Each of these pictures / links posted will become a post on my page under a Custom Post Type. I am using Gravity Form + Custom Post Types.

Does anyone know a path to integrate the Flickr part? Where an user can just paste the link of a Flickr photo page, and we will process to get just the picture url for say, medium size format, and make that a feature image of the post? It would be nice to have the picture (or thumbnail) displayed right after the user paste the Flickr link into a text field.

I've been searching and thinking yet haven't found an ideal solution yet. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find how to upload pics with Gravity Forms to Dropbox

http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/questions-about-the-file-image-uploader

From Dropbox you can use this http://beta.wappwolf.com/ to send your pics elsewhere

Maybe is not the shortest way but, it should work :)